# Create Dict Like Object without Using Inheritance

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I need to create an object that act just like a `dict`, but I cannot use `dict` for inheritance.  I want to pass the object into an array in pandas, and the `set_value` method fails if the class inherits from `dict` with a dimension error.  This means I need my `class` to act just like a dictionary, but not inherit at all from `dict`.  Most of the examples show how to do this by inheriting from `dict.

Somethings I don't know how to solve:

- If have property called JSON, the object tries to get the  value.

Is there a way to solve that issue?

```
###########################################################################
class BaseGeometry(object):
    _dict = None
    _ao = None
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, iterable, **kwargs):
        if iterable is None:
            iterable = {}
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            iterable[k] = v
        self._dict = iterable
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._dict)
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    __repr__ = __str__

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == '_dict':
            return self._dict
        elif name in {'_ao','_type', '_HASARCPY', '_HASSHAPELY',
                   '_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_'}:
            return self.__dict__[name]
        elif name in self._dict:
            return self._dict[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("No such attribute: " + name)
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == '_dict':
            self.__dict__['_dict'] = value
        elif name in {'_ao','_type', '_HASARCPY', '_HASSHAPELY',
                   '_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_'}:
            self.__dict__[name] = value
        else:
            self._dict[name] = value
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    __getitem__ = __getattr__
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    __setitem__ = __setattr__
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        if name in self._dict:
            del self._dict[name]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("No such attribute: " + name)
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __iter__(self):
        for k,v in self._dict.items():
            yield k,v
```

### UPDATE: ERROR MESSAGE

`builtins.ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

This is being caused when pandas does an `if` check.  If it's an object, not `dict` it works.

I also get this error:

`builtins.ValueError: cannot set using a list-like indexer with a different length than the value`

Comment: Because Pandas does not being given a 'dict' when you set a value.

Comment: This is a pure case of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Show us the actual error pandas gives you. It will probably be much easier to fix than coming up with an implementation of a dict which is not a dict, but it is a dict.

Comment: @DeepSpace - I understand what you are saying, but a dict like object is what I need due to the fact that I'm going to modify an existing code base.

Comment: @DeepSpace I posted the error message

Comment: Take a look at [`collections.UserDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict), but I would be unsurprised if avoiding `dict` inheritance turns out to solve nothing.